# Must every Twitter API request live in an ACAccount request?

Tags: ios5, twitter

I created a simple Twitter Manager that works as a model. 
For this model i added a property "account" to store the ACAccount... now if i try to launch an Api request like code shown here i get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`:

```c
-(void)requestFollowers{    
    // Build a twitter request
    TWRequest *followersRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL_FOLLOWERS] 
                                                      parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.account.username,@"-1",nil] 
                                                                                             forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"screen_name",@"cursor",nil]] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

    [followersRequest setAccount:self.account];

    [followersRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) 
     {
         //DO SOMETHING

     }];
}
```

While whenever i launch the same method within an Account request it works...

```c
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted){
        NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0) 
        {   
            self.account = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0]; 
             //HERE I LAUNCH PREVIOUS SHOWED METHOD
            [self requestFollowers];                
        }
    }
}];
```

Thus, i'm asking if every request for the API must live into an Account Request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved a similar issue with my TWRequest by simply retaining the ACAccountStore in an instance variable.